# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TestModel'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I was trying to add a new MVC template to an existing site that I've been developing for the last few months.  I have a couple custom controllers/models setup that are working fine.  Today I tried to add another new template and I've run into this error that I can't get past. Umbraco version is 7.04.

First, the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JAHn.png

**~/Views/MVCTest.cshtml**

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<TestModel>
@{
  Layout = null;
}
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

**~/App_Code/Test/TestController.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Models;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;

public class TestController : RenderMvcController {
  public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model) {
    var test = new TestModel(model.Content, model.CurrentCulture);
    return base.Index(test);
  }
}
```

**~/App_Code/Test/TestModel.cs**

```
using System.Globalization;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Web.Models;

public class TestModel : RenderModel {
  public TestModel(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture)
    : base(content, culture) {

    }

}
```

Anybody see any obvious issues?  It's really strange because I have essentially the same exact code working for some other custom models and controllers so I'm totally confused as to why any new types give me this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is almost right, the problem is that your view is called `MVCtest.cshtml` because presumably your document type is called `MVCtest`, however your Controller is just called `TestController` and not `MVCTestController`.

Umbraco's routing is quite specific in that it will route all traffic for a specific document type via a controller with a matching name.

Also, you don't need the `return base.Index(test);`, just `return CurrentTemplate(test);`

An additional point is that Umbraco will by default attempt to route via the `Index` action unless you have actions that match the name of your templates. So, you could have multiple templates each with separate actions.

Comment: Thank you! It was totally my naming conventions, I had no idea Umbraco was so specific!

Comment: My pleasure and thanks @dampee. Actually Umbraco being specific is a good thing as you can always rely on the direct relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need the `TestModel` two (2) constructors?

Comment: No, in the source only one (actually either) is required.

Comment: I always add two ctors: 
  public MyModel(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture)
            : base(content, culture) {}
  public MyModel(IPublishedContent content)
            : base(content) {}

Comment: And you can, but if you look at the Umbraco source the `CultureInfo` is set for you by Umbraco if you only use the `RenderModel(IPublishedContent content)` ctor. So there is no need to code the second unless you are purposefully setting the Culture to something other than the default.

Comment: In actual fact you could create your own base class and hide the ctor: `public BaseRenderModel() : base(UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent) { }`. This makes your view models much cleaner.